# Upgrade PostgreSQL from 9.6 to 11

Tags: django, postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-11

I'm using the PostgreSQL v9.6 database for my Django (v1.11) application and I want to move to PostgreSQL v11.

Are there any changes that need to be made before? Any risks for my Django application? Any pitfalls to avoid?
I've checked the release notes of PostgreSQL but I just want to know if anyone has experienced issues after upgrading.

Moreover, are there any "important" tests that could be done to ensure that it works properly?

Comment: It will not if all steps will be followed. but don't forget to take complete backup before upgrade